# FullCalendar isn't showing events

Tags: asp.net, fullcalendar

I'm using the arshaw's FullCalendar jQuery plugin on ASP.NET 4. Everything is okay, the events are fetched, but they're not displayed in the calendar. I'm sure they're fetched, FireBug shows the response like this:

```
{"d":[{"__type":"CalendarioEvento","title":"Samara Dos Santos 
Freitas","start":1304441400,"color":null},
{"__type":"CalendarioEvento","title":"Apae","start":1304443800,"color":null},
{"__type":"CalendarioEvento","title":"Apae","start":1304447400,"color":null},
{"__type":"CalendarioEvento","title":"Samara Dos Santos 
Freitas","start":1304449800,"color":null}]}
```

I also tried a events array manually serialization, but it doesn't work.

The $.ajax() in fullcalendar.js:

```
$.ajax($.extend({}, ajaxDefaults, source, {
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(events) {
                    events = events || [];
                    var res = applyAll(success, this, arguments);
                    if ($.isArray(res)) {
                        events = res;
                    }
                    callback(events);
                },
                error: function() {
                    applyAll(error, this, arguments);
                    callback();
                },
                complete: function() {
                    applyAll(complete, this, arguments);
                    popLoading();
                }
            }));
```

Here's my VB code to fecth the events from the database and return them to the plugin:

```
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager
Imports Newtonsoft.Json

<System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()> _
Partial Class _Default
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Private Shared Function ToUnixTimespan(ByVal d As DateTime) As Long
    Dim time As New TimeSpan()
    time = d.ToUniversalTime().Subtract(New DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0))

    Return CType(Math.Truncate(time.TotalSeconds), Int64)
End Function

Private Shared Function FromUnixTimespan(ByVal s As String) As DateTime
    Dim time As DateTime = New DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
    Return time.AddSeconds(s)
End Function

<WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function ListarEventos(ByVal starte As String, ByVal ende As String) As List(Of CalendarioEvento)
    Dim conexaoSql As New SqlConnection(ConnectionStrings("praeConnectionString").ConnectionString)
    Dim comandoSql As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("spListarEventosCalendario", conexaoSql)
    comandoSql.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    comandoSql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bitPendentes", 0)
    comandoSql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@agendamentos", "188,135")
    comandoSql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@start", FromUnixTimespan(starte))
    comandoSql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@end", FromUnixTimespan(ende))
    comandoSql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@veiculo", "M01")
    Dim eventos As List(Of CalendarioEvento) = New List(Of CalendarioEvento)
    Try
        conexaoSql.Open()
        Dim sdrEventos As SqlDataReader = comandoSql.ExecuteReader
        While sdrEventos.Read
            Dim evento As New CalendarioEvento
            evento.title = StrConv(sdrEventos("vchNome").ToString, VbStrConv.ProperCase)
            evento.start = ToUnixTimespan(Convert.ToDateTime(sdrEventos("vchData") + " " + sdrEventos("vchHora")))
            eventos.Add(evento)
        End While
    Catch ex As Exception

    Finally
        conexaoSql.Close()
    End Try
    comandoSql.Parameters("@bitPendentes").Value = 1
    Try
        conexaoSql.Open()
        Dim sdrEventos As SqlDataReader = comandoSql.ExecuteReader
        While sdrEventos.Read
            Dim evento As New CalendarioEvento
            evento.title = StrConv(sdrEventos("vchNome").ToString, VbStrConv.ProperCase)
            evento.start = ToUnixTimespan(Convert.ToDateTime(sdrEventos("vchData") + " " + sdrEventos("vchHora")))
            evento.color = "#6AB0D8"
            eventos.Add(evento)
        End While
    Catch ex As Exception

    Finally
        conexaoSql.Close()
    End Try
    Return eventos
End Function
```

End Class

Anyone have a solution?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please post the pertinent javascript code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the catch

instead of

```
events = events || [];
```

use

```
events = events.d || [];
```

with d parameter and it will work.
If you want to know what is this freaking d, you should update your rss reader with [Encosia](http://encosia.com) blog. This d is introduced in ASP.NET 3.5 (It's not present in MVC, beacuse it's different framework).

[Quote from his blog](http://encosia.com/2009/02/10/a-breaking-change-between-versions-of-aspnet-ajax/):

> This is the case with all ASMX
>   services JSON serialized through the
>   ASP.NET AJAX Extensions in ASP.NET
>   3.5. Even if you’re only returning a scalar return value, such as a string,
>   int, or boolean, the result will
>   always be enclosed within the “d”. Why
>   did it change? While I wish this
>   unexpected change had been more
>   clearly announced, it’s a good one.
>   Here’s how Dave Reed explained it to
>   me:
>
> {"d": 1 }
>
> Is not a valid JavaScript statement,
>   where as this:
>
> [1] Is.
>
> So the wrapping of the "d" parameter
>   prevents direct execution of the
>   string as script. No Object or Array
>   constructor worries.
>
> [] is JavaScript’s array literal
>   notation, allowing you to instantiate
>   an array without explicitly calling a
>   constructor. To expand on Dave’s
>   explanation, simply consider this
>   code: ["Dave", alert("Do Evil"),
>   "Ward"] That literal array declaration
>   will execute the alert in most
>   browsers. Danger!

You could even do some workaround to make it work both with ASP.NET 2.0 and ASP.NET 3.5+

```
 if (events.hasOwnProperty('d')){
   events = events.d || [];
 }
 else {
   events = events || [];
 }
```

And since jquery version 1.5.1 you can use

```
$.ajaxSetup({
            converters: {
            // Evaluate text as a json expression
            "text json": function(data) {
            var res = $.parseJSON(data);
            return res.hasOwnProperty(‘d’) ? res.d : res;
}
```

so you don't even have to touch the fullcallendar.js code

Comment: Awesome! I suspected that, but didn't know what to do. Thank you, guy!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what "d" is and what _type is but this how it should look from the server

```
[{"id":17667,"title":"Daily - 30days","allDay":false,"start":"6/4/2011 1:00:00 PM","end":"6/4/2011 2:00:00 PM","color":"#C0F8F9","textColor":"#000000","isCustomProperty":true},
{"id":17669,"title":"Test","allDay":true,"start":"6/5/2011 12:00:00 AM","end":"6/5/2011 11:59:00 PM","color":"#C0F8F9","textColor":"#000000","isCustomProperty":true},
{"id":17677,"title":"Weekly - Month","allDay":false,"start":"6/1/2011 1:00:00 PM","end":"6/1/2011 2:00:00 PM","color":"#C0F8F9","textColor":"#000000","isCustomProperty":true}]
```

I think it's probably since you wrapped the stuff around with "d" first then "_type" full calendar probably can't extract it.

Comment: Hmm... If I set the events manually, the calendar shows them.
If I manually serialize the array the "__type" disappears, but the "d" continues (it's a bult-in ASP.NET 4 property).
And when I was using ASP.NET 2, there wasn't the "d"; if I pass a not manually serialized events array, the calendar worked perfectly.

Comment: So it works if you don't have the "d"? I am not sure what this "d" is for. I use asp.net mvc 3.0 with .net 4 with the Json() built in from MVC and never seen it that "d" before

Comment: Probably it is. I've tried removing, to test. Do you know how to?

Comment: @dkosilva - no I don't know how to remove. I guess you could make a another project that is like 3.5 that would not have it and copy your code in that and see it works.

Comment: I'll do this. Later I came back.

Comment: @dkosilva - you could also try http://james.newtonking.com/ instead of using the built in Json. See if that helps.

Comment: @chobo2, I'm not using the built-in funcionality. In fact I'm just returning the array.

Comment: Your just returning an array? I am not sure if you can just return an array and it will be able to turn that into json.

Comment: I tried you suggest, but again doesn't work and the d property is there. And the library on the james.newtonking.com returned the same Json returned by the bult-in funcionality.

Answer (score 0):

check out the following

[How to use Jquery fullcalender in asp.net](http://aspdotnetcodebook.blogspot.com/2010/08/how-to-use-jquery-fullcalender-in.html)

**EDIT**

There is some issue in fullcalender plugin.Follow the steps provided in [this](http://jake1164.blogspot.com/2010/06/jquery-fullcalendar-and-aspnet.html) link and modified the plug in code accordingly

Comment: I had made like this, geek, but doesn't work. Thank you for answering.

Comment: @dkosilva:If you still faces any issue let me know

Comment: at first, when it worked (.NET 2.0), I followed this tutorial, but in the current version is not working. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

@nemke: Your answer helped me with getting my code to work. Thank you! I did have to deserialize my result from the web service like this, though:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    converters: {
        // Evaluate text as a json expression
        "text json": function (data) {
            var res = $.parseJSON(data);
            return res.hasOwnProperty('d') ? Sys.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.deserialize('(' + res.d + ')') : Sys.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.deserialize('(' + res + ')');
        }
    }
});
```